# Accessing and changing text in jTextField from another class

Tags: java, swing, class

I'm currently having problems with accessing and changing the text of jTextField from another class.

I'm building an application which has two jTextFields elements in first UI. 
This two elements serve as boxes for the selected date in the second UI.

When a user clicks on the jTextField (first UI) it opens the second UI with a calendar, from which a user selects a date. When user selects a date and confirms it, the selected date appears in the jTextField  as text in the first UI.

I'm having problems in the last bit. I want to fire the update method for the jTextField (in the first UI which is in the different class) from the class in which I have the second UI.

Comment: So you're running two separate frames?

Comment: Yes, I'm running two separate frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC pattern is perfect for that.
Otherwise, you can add in the constructor of your second class a parameter with the field object. Updating should work. Example (it's been a long time that I have coded in Java, so I may put wrong things) :

```
public MyFrame1() {
   //...
   JTextField dateField = new JTextField();
   //...
   dateField.addClickListener(new EventListener(){
        new MyFrame2(dateField);
   });
}


public MyFrame2(dateField) {
    //...
    // When updating :
         dateField.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned something new today. Can you please post an example of your implementation please.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too much code if your second frame, you could just make it a modal `JDialog` instead of that second GUI and have it as an inner class of the main GUI class

```
public class MainGUI extends JFrame {

    private MyDialog dialog;

    public MainGIU(){
        dialog = new MyDialog(this, true);

        // some action sets the dialog visible
    }

    private class MyDialog extends JDialog {
        public MyDialog(Frame frame, boolean modal){
             super(frame, modal);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above setup, you can access any field from the `MainGUI` inside the `MyDialog`. But as Vin243 noted, this *is* the perfect example of when to use the MVC pattern